# EJB security custom JACC provider

Tags: security, ejb, jacc

our project has a very detailed authorization pattern

so i had to implement my own JACC provider.

now i have a problem with EJB security.

i have an EJB method and i want to limit access to it based

on its argument values

for example consider the `delete(String arg1)` EJB method

i want a user be able to run it with `arg1=='something'`

and be not able to run it otherwise

how could i access to method's argument values?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you taken a look at EJB interceptors? They have full access to the method's parameters and return value, and can decide to let the call pass through or block it.

Comment: thank you, i have looked at them, they are very useful. i have tried to check permission in interceptor class, but i don't know how to do it exactly, i have defined a new type of permission(including parameter values), but i don't know how to pass it to JACC provider for checking. could you please help me about this? thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I know about interceptors but I know nearly nothing about how to access JACC.